# Problem in the table of latex

Tags: longtable

I need help in the latex please that is really argent. I made a long table but the problem is that data from the end not move to the next page in a proper way.This is my full code?????

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}cccc@{}}
    \caption{Bacterial species in gut microbiota of  Cx.quiquefasciatus}
    \label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sr.No} &
    \textbf{Bacterial Genera} &
    \textbf{Species} &
    \textbf{Accession No.} \\* \midrule
    \endhead
    %
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Acinetobacter}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. baumannii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{APD20249}} \\* \cmidrule(r){1-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{6}{*}{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{6}{*}{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. beijerinckii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. junii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A.lwofii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. pittii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. soli}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. schindleri}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Arthrobacter}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A.creationlyticus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{ATCC21022}} \\* \cmidrule(r){1-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Aerococcus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A. uurinaeequi}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Aeromonas}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A.enteropelogenes}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{AY522923}} \\* \cmidrule(r){1-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A.hydrophila}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A.ichthiosmia}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{A.veronii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Bacillus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B. anthracis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{AL009126}} \\* \cmidrule(r){1-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{6}{*}{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{6}{*}{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B.aryabhattai}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B.cereus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B.circulans}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B.flexus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B.nealsonii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{B.subtilis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{6}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Citrobacter}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{C. braaki}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{MN548424}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C.frei} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Delftia}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{D. lacust}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{JOUB01000005} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{8}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{Enterobacter}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E. asburiae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{ERR1854846}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.cancergenus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.cloacae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.ludwigii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{9}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{Enterococcus}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.caccae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{AY754011}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.faecalis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.hirae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.silesiacus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{10}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Escherichia}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.coli}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{AE005671}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.hermannii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{11}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textit{Exiguobacterium}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.aurantiacum}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{ACB62096}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E.indicum}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{E. profundum}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{12} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Janibacter}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{J. melonis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{PRJNA13546} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{13}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textit{Klebsiella}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{K.oxytoca}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{HF536482}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{K.pneumoniae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{K.variicola}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{14}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textit{Kocuria}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{K.marina}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{CP035504}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K.carniphila} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{K.palustris}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{15} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Kytococcus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{K.schroeteri}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MN911377} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{16} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Lactococcus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{L.lactis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{HM219853} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{17} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Leucobacter}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{L.tardus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MT335639} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{18} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Lysinibacillus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{L.macroides}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MTD16782} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{19}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{Microbacterium}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.arborescens}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{MG754432}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.imperiale}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.maritypicum}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.oxydans}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{20}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Micrococcus}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.lylae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{KM37667}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.yunnanensis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{21} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Morganella}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{M.morganii}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{KY12032} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{22}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Pantoea}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.anthophila}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{CP022427}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.dispersa}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{23} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Proteus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.vulgaris}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{AJ250100} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{24}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Providencia}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.alcalifaciens}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{KF295828}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.rettgeri}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{25}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{Pseudomonas}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.cuatrocienegasensis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{MH235964}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.aeruginosa}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.stutzeri}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{P.beteli}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{26} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Serratia}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.marcescens}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{KM492926} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{27} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Shigella}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.flexneri}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{AF288197} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{28} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Sporosarcina}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.luteola}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LT601384} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{11}{*}{29}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{11}{*}{\textit{Staphylococcus}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.agnetis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{11}{*}{CP028841}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.aureus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.caprae}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.epidermidis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.gallinarum}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.haemolyticus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.hominis}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.saprophyticus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.succinus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.warneri}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.xylosus}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{Stenotrophomonas}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{S.maltophilia}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MT 335840} \\* \midrule
    31 &
    \textit{Vagococcus} &
    \textit{V.fluvialis} &
    SS1994627 \\* \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: No problem here. What do you mean by “data from the end not move to the next page in a proper way”

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You show us only a fragment of code. We can easy  help you if you will extend your code framgnend to small but complee document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. In preamble should be only relevant packages and definition (if exist).

Comment: Not related, but it's weird to use vertical lines within booktabs…

Comment: Yes that is not move to the next page in a proper way.

Comment: don't  use `\\*` but also the page breaking depends on the page size and context but you have only provided a fragment that we can not run. why all the `\multicolumn`

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause of `longtable` not breaking across pages is to have it inside a `table` environment, which is an error.

Here's a version of the table that gets rid of all `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` instructions.

The trick is to create subtables for the species' names. If you prefer vertical centering of the serial number, genus name and accession string, just remove the `[t]` from the definition of `\species`.

I set the species column left aligned to avoid too many waves. Change `l` to `c` if you really prefer centering, both in the argument to `longtable` and in the definition of `\species`.

Note that using a nested tabular avoids problems with page breaking, as the “species' cell” is a single object.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\newcommand{\species}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}cclc@{}}
\caption{Bacterial species in gut microbiota of  Cx\@. quiquefasciatus}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Sr.No} &
\textbf{Bacterial Genera} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Species}} &
\textbf{Accession No.} \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{\tablename~\ref{tab:my-table} continued} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Sr.No} &
\textbf{Bacterial Genera} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Species}} &
\textbf{Accession No.} \\ \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & \textit{Acinetobacter} &
  \species{
    \textit{A. baumannii} \\
    \textit{A. beijerinckii} \\
    \textit{A. junii} \\
    \textit{A. lwofii} \\
    \textit{A. pittii} \\
    \textit{A. soli} \\
    \textit{A. schindleri}
  } &
APD20249 \\
\midrule

2 & \textit{Arthrobacter} & \textit{A. creationlyticus} & ATCC21022 \\
\midrule

3 & \textit{Aerococcus} & \textit{A. uurinaeequi} & ATCC21022 \\
\midrule

4 & \textit{Aeromonas} &
  \species{
    \textit{A. enteropelogenes} \\
    \textit{A. hydrophila} \\
    \textit{A. ichthiosmia} \\
    \textit{A. veronii}
  } &
AY522923 \\
\midrule

5 & \textit{Bacillus} &
  \species{
    \textit{B. anthracis} \\
    \textit{B. aryabhattai} \\
    \textit{B. cereus} \\
    \textit{B. circulans} \\
    \textit{B. flexus} \\
    \textit{B. nealsonii} \\
    \textit{B. subtilis}
  } &
AL009126 \\
\midrule

6 & \textit{Citrobacter} &
  \species{
    \textit{C. braaki} \\
    \textit{C. frei}
  } &
MN548424 \\
\midrule

7 & \textit{Delftia} & \textit{D. lacust} & JOUB01000005 \\
\midrule

8 & \textit{Enterobacter} &
  \species{
    \textit{E. asburiae} \\
    \textit{E. cancergenus} \\
    \textit{E. cloacae} \\
    \textit{E. ludwigii} 
  } &
ERR1854846 \\
\midrule

9 & \textit{Enterococcus} &
  \species{
    \textit{E. caccae} \\
    \textit{E. faecalis} \\
    \textit{E. hirae} \\
    \textit{E. silesiacus}
  } &
AY754011 \\
\midrule

10 & \textit{Escherichia} &
  \species{
    \textit{E. coli} \\
    \textit{E. hermannii}
  } &
AE005671 \\
\midrule

11 & \textit{Exiguobacterium} &
  \species{
    \textit{E. aurantiacum} \\
    \textit{E.indicum} \\
    \textit{E. profundum} 
  } &
ACB62096 \\
\midrule

12 & \textit{Janibacter} & \textit{J. melonis} & PRJNA13546 \\
\midrule

13 & \textit{Klebsiella} &
  \species{
    \textit{K. oxytoca} \\
    \textit{K. pneumoniae} \\
    \textit{K. variicola}
  } &
HF536482 \\
\midrule

14 & \textit{Kocuria} &
  \species{
    \textit{K. marina} \\
    \textit{K. carniphila} \\
    \textit{K. palustris}
  } &
CP035504 \\
\midrule

15 & \textit{Kytococcus} & \textit{K. schroeteri} & MN911377 \\
\midrule

16 & \textit{Lactococcus} & \textit{L. lactis} & HM219853 \\
\midrule

17 & \textit{Leucobacter} & \textit{L. tardus} & MT335639 \\
\midrule

18 & \textit{Lysinibacillus} & \textit{L. macroides} & MTD16782 \\
\midrule

19 & \textit{Microbacterium} &
  \species{
    \textit{M. arborescens} \\
    \textit{M. imperiale} \\
    \textit{M. maritypicum} \\
    \textit{M. oxydans}
  } &
MG754432
\\
\midrule

20 & \textit{Micrococcus} &
  \species{
    \textit{M. lylae} \\
    \textit{M.yunnanensis}
  } &
KM37667 \\
\midrule

21 & \textit{Morganella} & \textit{M. morganii} & KY12032 \\
\midrule

22 & \textit{Pantoea} &
  \species{
    \textit{P. anthophila} \\
    \textit{P. dispersa}
  } &
CP022427 \\
\midrule

23 & \textit{Proteus} & \textit{P. vulgaris} & AJ250100 \\
\midrule

24 & \textit{Providencia} &
  \species{
    \textit{P. alcalifaciens} \\
    \textit{P.rettgeri}
  } &
KF295828 \\
\midrule

25 & \textit{Pseudomonas} &
  \species{
    \textit{P. cuatrocienegasensis} \\
    \textit{P. aeruginosa} \\
    \textit{P. stutzeri} \\
    \textit{P. beteli}
  } &
MH235964 \\
\midrule

26 & \textit{Serratia} & \textit{S. marcescens} & KM492926 \\
\midrule

27 & \textit{Shigella} & \textit{S. flexneri} & AF288197 \\
\midrule

28 & \textit{Sporosarcina} & \textit{S. luteola} & LT601384 \\
\midrule

29 & \textit{Staphylococcus} &
  \species{
    \textit{S. agnetis} \\
    \textit{S. aureus} \\
    \textit{S. caprae} \\
    \textit{S. epidermidis} \\
    \textit{S. gallinarum} \\
    \textit{S. haemolyticus} \\
    \textit{S. hominis} \\
    \textit{S. saprophyticus} \\
    \textit{S. succinus} \\
    \textit{S. warneri} \\
    \textit{S. xylosus}
 } &
CP028841 \\
\midrule

30 & \textit{Stenotrophomonas} & \textit{S. maltophilia} & MT 335840 \\* \midrule

31 & \textit{Vagococcus} & \textit{V. fluvialis} & SS1994627 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, here's an excerpt with vertical centering and species name centering as well.

[image]

I also added a space after periods ending genus abbreviations: be consistent, either no space always or space always.

Comment: Thank u so much. Can I send u more data to make my table in latex.

Comment: how we made the the table of images within the 20 rows and 4 column

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @egreg answer (+1). Small differences are:

- removed are also all `multirow` cells
- removed are all `\itshape` commands. Instead of it their use is modified column specifications:

```
    \begin{longtable}{@{} c >{\itshape}l
                            >{\itshape}l
                           l @{}}
```

Considering aforementioned, the MWE, which reproduce your table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{@{} c >{\itshape}l
                            >{\itshape}l
                           l @{}}
\caption{Bacterial species in gut microbiota of  Cx.quiquefasciatus}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Sr.No} 
    &   \textbf{\textup{Bacterial Genera}} 
        &   \textbf{\textup{Species}} 
            &   \textbf{Accession No.}  \\* 
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Bacterial species in gut microbiota of  Cx.quiquefasciatus (cont.)}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Sr.No}
    &   \textbf{\textup{Bacterial Genera}}
        &   \textbf{\textup{Species}}
            &   \textbf{Accession No.}  \\*
    \midrule
\endhead
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\emph{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
    %
1   & Acinetobacter     & A. baumannii          & APD20249      \\
    &                   & A. beijerinckii       &               \\
    &                   & A. junii              &               \\
    &                   & A.lwofii              &               \\
    &                   & A. pittii             &               \\
    &                   & A. soli               &               \\
    &                   & A. schindleri         &               \\
    \midrule
2   & Arthrobacter      & A.creationlyticus     & ATCC21022     \\
    \midrule
3   & Aerococcus        & A. uurinaeequi        & AY522923      \\
    \cmidrule{1-3}
4   & Aeromonas         & A.enteropelogenes     &               \\
    &                   & A.hydrophila          &               \\
    &                   & A.ichthiosmia         &               \\
    &                   & A.veronii             &               \\
    \midrule
5   & Bacillus          & B. anthracis          & AL009126      \\
    &                   & B.aryabhattai         &               \\
    &                   & B.cereus              &               \\
    &                   & B.circulans           &               \\
    &                   & B.flex                &               \\
    &                   & B.nealsonii           &               \\
    &                   & B.subtilis            &               \\
    \midrule
6   & Citrobacter       & C. braaki             & MN548424      \\
    &                   & C.frei                &               \\
    \midrule
7   & Delftia           & D. lacust             & JOUB01000005  \\
    \midrule
8   & Enterobacter      & E. asburiae           & ERR1854846    \\
    &                   & E.cancergenus         &               \\
    &                   & E.cloacae             &               \\
    &                   & E.ludwigii            &               \\
    \midrule
9   & Enterococcus      & E.caccae              & AY754011      \\
    &                   & E.faecalis            &               \\
    &                   & E.hirae               &               \\
    &                   & E.silesiacus          &               \\
    \midrule
10 & Escherichia        & E.coli                & AE005671      \\
    &                   & E.hermannii           &               \\
    \midrule
11  & Exiguobacterium   & E.aurantiacum         & ACB62096      \\
    &                   & E.indicum             &               \\
    &                   & E. profundum          &               \\*
    \midrule
12  & Janibacter        & J. melonis            & PRJNA13546    \\
    \midrule
13  & Klebsiella        & K.oxytoca             & HF536482      \\*
    &                   & K.pneumoniae          &               \\
    &                   & K.variicola           &               \\
    \midrule
14  &  Kocuria          & K.marina              & CP035504      \\
    &                   & K.carniphila          &               \\
    &                   & K.palustris           &               \\
    \midrule
15 & Kytococcus         & K.schroeteri          & MN911377      \\
    \midrule
16 & Lactococcus        & L.lactis              & HM219853      \\
    \midrule
17  & Leucobacter       & L.tardus              & MT335639      \\
    \midrule
18  & Lysinibacillus    & L.macroides           & MTD16782      \\
    \midrule
19  & Microbacterium    & M.arborescens         & MG754432      \\
    &                   & M.imperiale           &               \\
    &                   & M.maritypicum         &               \\
    &                   & M.oxydans             &               \\
    \midrule
20  & Micrococcus       & M.lylae               & KM37667       \\
    &                   & M.yunnanensis         &               \\
     \midrule
21  & Morganella        & M.morganii            & KY12032       \\
    \midrule
22  & Pantoea           & P.anthophila          &  CP02242      \\
    &                   & P.dispersa            &               \\
    \midrule
23  & Proteus           & P.vulgaris            & AJ250100      \\
    \midrule
24  & Providencia       & P.alcalifaciens       & KF295828      \\
    &                   & P.rettgeri            &               \\
    \midrule
25  & Pseudomonas       & P.cuatrocienegasensis & MH235964      \\
    &                   & P.aeruginosa          &               \\
    &                   & P.stutzeri            &               \\
    &                   & P.beteli              &               \\
    \midrule
26  & Serratia          & S.marcescens          & KM492926      \\
    \midrule
27  & Shigella          & S.flexneri            & AF288197      \\
    \midrule
28  & Sporosarcina      & S.luteola             & LT601384      \\
    \midrule
29  & Staphylococcus    & S.agnetis             & CP028841      \\*
    &                   & S.aureus              &               \\*
    &                   & S.caprae              &               \\*
    &                   & S.epidermidis         &               \\*
    &                   & S.gallinarum          &               \\*
    &                   & S.haemolyticus        &               \\*
    &                   & S.hominis             &               \\*
    &                   & S.saprophyticus       &               \\*
    &                   & S.succinus            &               \\*
    &                   & S.warneri             &               \\*
    &                   & S.xylosus             &               \\*
    \midrule
30  & Stenotrophomonas  & S.maltophilia         & MT 335840     \\
    \midrule
31 & Vagococcus        & V.fluvialis            & SS1994627     \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can u please help me in this table. The problem in this table that is not move to the next page in a proper way and kindly mention the size of the figure as well as the place of the figure.

Comment: @MonaIshtiaq,if you test my MWE, you should see, that table is nicely breaks over pages. For any further help, please edit your question and extend your code snippet to complete small document (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document`, similarly as is done in my answer) , which reproduce your problem.